# MySQL - Preg Replace

Tags: php, mysql, sql, preg-replace

I have 2 column in table: C1, C2

I want to update

```
C2 = Replace(C1, everything not a-zA-Z0-9\s(space), "")
```

but I can't find out how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question: [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

You can use [regex in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: I thought regex in MYSQL only return 0 or 1 like preg_match.

Comment: . mysql_real_escape_string($match)